# Foursquare call to KO Observable Array: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable, foursquare

I'm trying to add the results of a Foursquare venues request to a KO Observable array. I can't solve the error of push being undefined. I assume this is because of the helper not processing the data appropriately.

I define the array and make the request

```
storelocations = ko.observableArray([]);

  var fourquarerequest = $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'XXXXrequestXXXXX',
    })
```

Then I attempt to go through the results, process them with a helper, and add each to the Observable Array

```
            fourquarerequest.done((response) => {

            var self = this
                data = response.response.venues;

                for (var name in data) {
                  shop = new shopdetails(data);
                  self.storelocations.push(shop);
                  console.log(storelocations);
                  }

                //console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            });
```

And here's the processing

```
  var shopdetails = function (shop) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = data.name;
    self.lat = data.lat;
    self.long = data.long;
    self.URL = data.url;
      if (typeof self.URL === 'undefined') {
          self.URL = "";
        }
  };
```

Comment: Seems to be a scope problem. Where exactly have you defined storelocations = ko.observableArray([])? Please show that as well in the code

Comment: sorry, the Stack Overflow formatting wasn't correct. It's fixed now, storelocations is defined above the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s a problem of scope. You have defined `self` inside the `foursquare.done` function and then written `self.storedlocations.push()`, even though `storedlocations` is a global variable.

Change it to `storedlocations.push()`.